# Safely Execute Stored Procedure Via DMZ Server

Tags: sql-server, security, email, web-server, stored-procedures

I'd like to execute a stored procedure via web application that connects to SQL Server. The procedure is to be activated by clicking a link in an email. The link will have to be accessible from a mobile 3g connection, so the link will exist on a DMZ server.

How can I go about protecting and securely setting up this link, without potentially compromising the SQL server?

Is there a safer way to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently risky about what you're trying to do, given that you follow a couple of standard security rules:

- Never expose variables used in the SQL query (ie GET or POST Variables) without ensuring they are clean before executing the query.
- Ensure the script can't do anything beyond what you expect
- If it is something the public shouldn't access make sure you password protect it
- Run the script as a user with the minimum privileges required to do the job. NOT Administrator!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resources you would have a SQL server separate from your web interface which sits in the DMZ. This is standard practice to isolate the SQL engine. Mobility interfaces get hammered by all kinds of traffic.